# Website Url trailing '/' issue

Tags: .net, url

So I'm working on a site, and when I launch it from Visual Studio, the default URL is https://loaclhost/GeoFencing/, but it gives me this an error:

```
ID3206: A SignInResponse message may only redirect within the current web application: '/Home/Api' is not allowed.
```

However, when I remove the trailing slash from the URL, the pages opens properly, but the new displayed URL when the page loads has the trailing slash on the end!

Anyone one know what's going on here?

Comment: This thread has various solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460720/error-a-signinresponse-message-may-only-redirect-within-the-current-web-applic

Comment: Unfortunately these don't help me, I already took a look at all of them :(